Is admittance control set by impedance control?
My goal is to use end effector as the ultrasound probe, so the sonographer can easily manipulate the end effector, allowing smooth motion of both translation and rotation.
Franka Emika robot provides impedance control, but not admittance control. After some reading, it seems like the inverse of impedance is admittance. Is it possible to achieve admittance control with impedance control? My thought is to use a low stiffness, high damping in impedance control.
Or, am I totally in the wrong direction? Thank you ;)
